# Installing pytesseract in windows 10

Tags: python

I hope you can help me I just installed the package using pip install from the command console. I have windows 10 and I use Python 3.6.
The problem I have is that when I want to use this library in a program that I downloaded, I get this error.

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can not find the specified file

This is my code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract      

im = Image.open("sample1.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

I realized that I only have these two files in the Scripts folder where python was installed.
pytesseract.exe and
pytesseract-script.py

Could you tell me if that's a problem?

Comment: hii joel i need your help in these

Comment: i am facing similar issue 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is the working directory from where you run python. The easiest way is to use an IDE such as pycharm where it will allow you to specify a working directory.

Alternatively, you need to make sure that the .jpg file is present from where you run python.

Another way would be to change the code and specify the path where the file is you want to OCR:
For example:

`im = Image.open("c:/temp/sample1.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

You must have an image called `sample1.jpg` in the same directory your python file is in.

Comment: Yes, I have that image in the same directory.